# What HTTP method is used with the opt-out link in Facebook custom audiences?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set up a custom endpoint to handle opt-out requests from a Facebook custom audience (and setting it as the "opt_out_link" (per Facebook's custom audience [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/v2.2#create)). What I don't know is what type of HTTP method to listen for. Should my endpoint be listening for a POST request? Also, what parameters are being sent to that opt out link? The user's ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the opt_out_link is just a URL to your existing unsubscribe form. It's displayed in the "Why am I seeing this" modal when you click on an ad.

Comment: Can you please give me more details about this opt out link? For example what are the required information to display in the unsubscribe form. If I have more than one page, how can i identify each page is blocked by the user? 
thank you

Comment: For further context, I was building a custom audience based on a mailing list, so the opt out link would be the URL to the opt-out page for that mailing list. That process is handled by the logic that handles all opt-out form submissions from all sources - nothing special needed by Facebook.